# What is Spring boot's version of @Assisted

Tags: java, spring, guice, assisted-inject

I'm wondering how to convert Guice's `@Assisted` annotation into spring boot in Java. For example I have this code:

```
@Inject
public Merge(@Named(Conf.MkvFields.CHAININPUT_DELAY) String chainInputDelay,
    @Named(Conf.MkvFields.REAL_TIME_PROCESSING),
    @Assisted MergeDefinition mergeDefinition) {
```

For example you'd have:

```
public interface MergeFactory { 
    public Merge createMerge(@Assisted MergeDefinition mergeDefinition);    
}
```

And then you'd have:

```
        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(MergeFactory.class));
```

And:

```
mergeFactory.createMerge(mergeDefinition));
```

I know how to convert `@Inject` and `@Named`, but I've been doing some research on the `@Assisted` but can't find anything? Is it possible? If so how would I do it?

Comment: [Wait, *what*?](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/Assisted.html)  What does it *do*??

Comment: You can use it when using the factory module builder to create new objects (I think) I've updated my post with an example.

Answer (score 0):

Spring has no equivalent to the Guice FactoryModuleBuilder. The closest equivalent would be a Spring @Configuration class that provides a factory bean that implements a factory interface whose methods accept arbitrary arguments from the application. 
Please refer the following link for details:
[What is the Spring equivalent to FactoryModuleBuilder, @AssistedInject, and @Assisted in Guice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29555705/what-is-the-spring-equivalent-to-factorymodulebuilder-assistedinject-and-ass)

Comment: The answer isn't very helpful, it seems to give you half an answer. It doesn't explain how you implement the factory though, as with guice you can create:     private final MergeFactory mergeFactory;
and initialize it in the constructor, but you can't do that with the answer to that question. Could you explain it to me?